# Are my interpretations of these groups correct?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am asked to decribe two groups as abstract abelian groups. The groups are:

$im(f)$ where $f: \mathbb Z^3 \rightarrow \mathbb Z^4$ is a group homomorphism sending $(a,b,c)$ to:

$(a+2b+8c,\;2a-2b+4c,\;-2b+12c,\;2a-4b+4c)$

and $\mathbb Z^4 / im(f)$

So I noted that $im(f) \leq \mathbb Z^4 $ is:

$\langle\;(1,2,0,2),\; (2,-2,-2,-4),\; (8,4,12,4)\;\rangle $

Since these row vectors are linearly independent and each have infinite additive order, I concluded that the group $im(f)$ is an infinite, additive, abelian group generated by three linearly independent elements each of infinite order. i.e. $im(f) \cong \mathbb Z^3$

Similarly, I noted that vectors in $\mathbb Z^4/im(f)$ are those with no components in the directions of the row vectors above, i.e. $\mathbb Z^4/im(f) = (im(f))^{\perp}$ I think is the correct notation.

Then since $r(f) = 3$, we see that $dim(\mathbb Z^4/im(f)) = 1$ and thus it must be an infinite, additive, abelian group generated by one element of infinite order. Thus $\mathbb Z^4 / im(f) \cong \mathbb Z$

Is this the right way to interpret these groups? I have a feeling that I may have misunderstood something somewhere because for some reason I feel like these isomorphisms are incorrect.

Any explanation or correction you may be able to offer would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What you're doing is basically linear algebra (implicitly) over a field, such as $\Bbb Q$; but $\Bbb Z$ is not a field (there are no multiplicative inverse), so it doesn't work the same way. For example, you can't use the concept of dimension like you did.

Comment: A lot of questions of this type are asked. I find it surprising that the people asking often do not appear to have been taught any method of solving them. There is an algorithm for solving all such problems, which involves reducing the matrix to Smith Normal Form. In this examplethe Smith Normal Form is a $3 \times 4$  matrix with entries $1,2,12$ on the main diagonal and $0$ elsewhere. Your reasoning is correct to give ${\rm im}(f) \cong Z^3$, but $Z^4/{\rm im}(f) \cong Z \oplus Z_2 \oplus Z_{12}$,

Comment: http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/SmithNormalForm.pdf for a nice explanation.